# Configure firebase rules for a contact form in production

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to configure a contact form under **firebase** for a production deployment. So far I have been using basic testing rules :

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true 
  }
}
```

I didn't particularly want to strengthen that for production, because given the use I make of it, no one will dig into my database, but google doesn't seem to agree with that and tells me that the link with the database will expire soon. I know how to fix the problem but it implies that the users are authenticated, except given the context there is no authentication possible on my site.

Comment: What's your question about this?  If you know how to fix the problem, I suggest doing that first.

Comment: @DougStevenson "... except given the context THERE  is no authentification POSSIBLE on my site"